# How to use GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis

I am using Spring Data Redis in order to cache some data using `@Cacheable`. I have multiple types of objects that need to be cached and I need the data from Redis to be in JSON format. I know that, by default, the serializer used is `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`, but with is the cached data is not human readable.

I order to save the data in JSON format I wanted to use `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` and I've created a custom `ObjectMapper` too:

```
  public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate (RedisConnectionFactory cf) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().failOnEmptyBeans(false)
        .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
        .indentOutput(false)
        .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        .modules(
            // Optional
            new Jdk8Module(),
            // Dates/Times
            new JavaTimeModule()
        )
        .featuresToDisable(
            SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
            DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS,
            SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS
        ).build();


    GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper);
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    return redisTemplate;
```

Using this `RedisTemplate` doesn't work and I always get back this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to <some class>
```

As I understood, when deserializing, Jackson doesn't know the type of the specific object since it's `Object` and creates a `LinkedHashMap` to hold the data. Maybe I am wrong with this, but how can I achieve saving the cached data as JSON for multiple types of objects with @Cacheble?

Answer (score 13):

You are right, you can achieve saving multiple types with `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer`. But in your example, you provide custom `ObjectMapper` to `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` and `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` doesn't configure [Jackson's default typing](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for you (you can check default constructor logic in `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer`). You have to tune it on your own and add this to your ObjectMapper

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);
```

This will include type information to JSON. Like this

```
{
  "@class": "com.example.Foo",
  "field": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Hi Aleh! Thanks for your bringing light on the subject!

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I'm injecting `ObjectMapper` so it should be the same object mapper (with the same configuration) as the one that Spring uses throughout the application right (e.g when deserializing JSON body of http requests) ?

Answer (score 5):

Since 2.10 ObjectMapper better to use

```
activateDefaultTyping(mapper.polymorphicTypeValidator, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL)
```